# Is <dl> element from XHTML 1.0 adapted to display a resource tag list or a subscription feed?

Tags: html, xhtml, semantics, semantic-web, semantic-markup

I wonder if the `<dl>` element from XHTML 1.0 is semantically valid to display a resource tag list, like that:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Tags</dt>
    <dd><a href="">Lorem</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="">Ipsum</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="">Dolor</a></dd>
</dl>
```

Or with a subscription feed, as the code bellow shows:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Feeds</dt>
    <dd><a href=""><img src="atom.png" alt="Atom" /></a></dd>
    <dd><a href=""><img src="rss.png" alt="RSS" /></a></dd>
</dl>
```

Or is the `<ul>` element more adapted to these examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dl` statement was originally intended to show a definition list. You want to show a list of available feeds. That's not "here's the lemma, here's the explanation" thingy that you use in a dictionary (and the relation is often 1:1, i.e., one `dt` and one `dd`).

So: no, the `dl` statement is not semantically the correct choice. `ul` is better suited, or a little table.

EDIT: for comparison, `<dt>Feed</dt><dd>An automatically retrievable set of information</dd>` would suit better. Note that "dt" means "definition term" and "dd" means "definition description" of "definition data".